# Using multiple CPU in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I dont have access to any GPU's, but I want to speed-up the training of my model created with PyTorch, which would be using more than 1 CPU. I will use the most basic model for example here.

All I want is this code to run on multiple CPU instead of just 1 (Dataset and Network class in *Appendix*).

```py
import pandas as pd

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


df = pd.read_pickle('path/to/data')

X = df.drop(columns=['target'])
y = df[['target']]

train_data = CustomDataset(X, y)
train_loader = DataLoader(
    dataset=train_data,
    batch_size=64
)

model = Network(X.shape[-1])
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

epochs = 10

for e in range(1, epochs + 1):
    train_loss = .0

    model.train()
    for batch_id, (data, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        target = model(data)
        loss = criterion(target, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()

    print('Epoch {}:\tTrain Loss: {:.4f}'.format(
        e,
        train_loss / len(train_loader)
    ))
```

Right now, this code is using only 1 CPU for 100% during training. I want the code to use 4 CPU's in the training process for 100%. There is so much different information out there on how to do this in the best way, that none of it is really working. I have tried different approaches using `model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model)` for example, but none of the worked.

Does someone now how to get the most performance for this code using 4 CPU? Thanks in Advance!

**APPENDIX**

```py
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(
        self,
        X,
        y,
    ):
        self.X = torch.Tensor(X.values)
        self.y = torch.Tensor(y.values)

    def __getitem__(
        self,
        index
    ):
        return self.X[index], self.y[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(X)


class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        input_size
    ):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size

        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(self.input_size, 32)
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(32, 1)


    def forward(self, data):
        output = self.linear_1(data)
        output = self.linear_2(output)

        return output
```

Answer (score 4):

[Torchrun](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.elastic.html) (included with Pytorch) makes this surprisingly easy.
How you want the CPUs to work together is not clear from your question, but I am assuming (because you refer to `DistributedDataParallel` that you would like to distribute the data across multiple cores which all do backward passes and broadcast their losses to the main process.

First, see if [`torch.distributed`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html?highlight=distrib#module-torch.distributed) is available: `torch.distributed.is_available()`.

Torchrun requires your script to have a few tweaks.
To initialize a process group, include

```py
import torch.distributed as dist
dist.init_process_group(backend="gloo")
```

The backend must be [gloo for CPUS](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html?highlight=gloo).
Torchrun sets the environment variables `MASTER_PORT`, `MASTER_ADDR`, `WORLD_SIZE`, and `RANK`, which are required for `torch.distributed`.

Then, to be able to broadcast the losses across cores, use

```py
local_rank = int(os.environ["LOCAL_RANK"])
model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(
    model,
    device_ids=[local_rank],
    output_device=local_rank,
)
```

Every core still gets to see the same data.
This can be more efficient using `DistributedSampler`:

```py
train_sampler = DistributedSampler(train_data)
train_loader = DataLoader(
    ...
    train_data,
    shuffle=False, # train_sampler will shuffle for you.
    sampler=train_sampler,
)
for e in range(1, epochs + 1):
    train_sampler.set_epoch(e)
    train(train_loader)
```

where `train(train_loader)` does the training steps. Note the `train_sampler.set_epoch(e)`.
This makes sure that every epoch the data is distributed to processes differently.

To start the training, run

```bash
torchrun
    --standalone
    --nnodes=1
    --nproc_per_node=$NUM_TRAINERS
    YOUR_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py
```

where `$NUM_TRAINERS` is the number of processes that work on improving your model.

It is recommended, not necessary, to include

```py
from torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors import record

@record
def main():
    # do train
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to see which process throws what error.

---

If I misunderstood your question and you only want more workers to load the data, then pass `num_workers=N` to `DataLoader`.
This ensures more workers (other than the main process) push the data into RAM while the current batch is being processed.

Comment: I'm using Jupiter Notebook. How to run torchrun @Siem

Comment: @user836026 I think torchrun is incompatible with ipython notebooks